# Internet explorer testing for mac and linux

Tags: internet-explorer, macos, testing, browser

Okey, so the question has probably been asked before, but I haven't found an answer. 
If I don't want to use a virtual-machine or crappy screenshot-webpages how could I test web-development for IE? 
Shouldn't Microsoft supply a tool for web developers to test their products? Because more and more people are developing on mac and linux and don't care about testing on IE until the end, and therefore misses a lot of bugs.

Comment: They only *should* supply such a tool if they cared. But plenty of people use IE because it's included with Windows. They don't need to promote the browser at all. They don't really care if you test your site with it, because most average users will blame your site, not IE. (Otherwise, they'd have switched to another browser already.) You're not going to find what you're looking for: the only option is virtualization or ugly hacks like screenshot-webpages.

Comment: Ha! Microsoft supporting development on other/competing platforms? They hardly even bothered supporting web standards.

Comment: Microsoft actually offers [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use IEs4Linux: http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page (wine)

But this is really crap.

The best option will be to setup a virtual machine. ;)

We have in our company, one virtual machine for every IE version.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] If I don't want to use a virtual-machine or crappy screenshot-webpages [...]

In that case, Wine is pretty much the only way to go.
WineBottler has nice predefined prefixes to run Internet Explorer on OSX using Wine.
It's extremely easy to install.

Checkout:
http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/

Comment: But it doesn't support IE9 :(

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? The only way to run IE on Mac is virtualization or Wine. Since you don't want virtualization, Wine is the only way to go. You can never expect IE to run flawlessly through Wine, it's just not developed to run on Mac or Linux. Why not running IE through virtualization? In the end, running native or virtualization is the only real solution. virtualization runs fine, certainly after using nLite, vLite or RT7Lite to slim-down Windows to the bare minimum.

Answer (score 0):

[October 2012]: A friend told me about browserling.com today which seems like a perfect solution (free + subscription). I wrote about it more in this thread: [Best way to test a webdesign for IE on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906061/best-way-to-test-a-webdesign-for-ie-on-a-mac/12995978#12995978)